# Cast from generic class property

Tags: c#, generics, expression

I want to cast from generic class of the propertyType and dont know how to do it.

I want to do something like this:

```
var key = Expression.Property(genericType, rule.ComparisonPredicate);
Type propertyType = typeof(T).GetProperty(rule.ComparisonPredicate).PropertyType;                                              
var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(propertyType);
var value = Expression.Constant((propertyType)converter.ConvertFromString(rule.ComparisonValue) );
```

but in the line var value i got an error :

> 'propertyType' is a variable but is used like a type

Comment: its just the name

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast to a variable, You should specify a real type

var value = Expression.Constant((**propertyType**)converter.ConvertFromString(rule.ComparisonValue) );

Comment: I want to do it dynamic, its not possible?

Comment: @maxman, unfortunately no. But You can use `object` as type and cast it in caller method but this is a bad approach

Comment: @maxman use `dynamic` type, but beware of its drawbacks. it can be much slower if not used correctly, its also not type-safe which means it can give you runtime errors that sometimes can be really hard to debug. so keep it minimal use.

Answer (score 0):

Try to cast the property type

(Type) typeof(T).GetProperty(rule.ComparisonPredicate).PropertyType